# Template as <script type="text/ng-template"> equivalent with angular 2

Tags: angular

Angularjs (e.g. angular 1) had this convenient behaviour of searching for a **<script type="text/ng-template">** element which had the id of the given template url before requesting it to the server.

Ex: The code below is not triggering any additional http request

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="mytemplate.html">
  This is a body for my template
</script>
<script>
    //...
    app.directive('myComponent', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html'  // does NOT trigger a http get
        };
    });
</script>
```

This does not seems to work using Angular 2.

```
@View({
   templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',  // will be fetched from server !
})
class MyComponent{}
```

Is there another way of achieving it ? Am I missing something ?

*ps: i do not wish to embbed all my html in my ts files...*

Comment: You can use `template` instead of `templateUrl`.

Comment: @EricMartinez that's what i meant by "i do not wish to embed my html": I'm generating template from an aspnet view (razor) ... it's not embeddable in a js file. And it's not convenient to edit html in a js string either.

Comment: it's much more convenient now that you can use backticks..

Comment: @foxx Sure, but it still feels like editing a string, not html. And i dont like having a view and its controller in the same source file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not, nor will it be, supported in Angular 2: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6126

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is interested, i found a simple workaround (a cleaner solution would be better, though)

```
function template(url, viewdef) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(url);
    if (elt && elt.getAttribute('type') == 'text/ng-template') {
        viewdef.template = elt.innerHTML;
    } else
        viewdef.templateUrl = url;
    return viewdef;
}

@View(template('mytemplate.html', {
    directives: [NgIf /*required directives*/]
}))
class MyComponent{}
```

But it assumes that the <script> is already present when this script is loaded.

**[EDIT] Better workaround**

I just came up with the simple idea to just override the `@View` decorator factory.

1) Create a  `viewoverride.ts` file

```
import * as ng from 'angular2/core'
let oldNgView = ng.View;
function ViewOverride(viewDef) {
    if (typeof viewDef.templateUrl == "string") {
        let elt = document.getElementById(viewDef.templateUrl);
        if (elt && elt.getAttribute('type') == 'text/ng-template') {
            viewDef.template = elt.innerHTML;
            delete viewDef.templateUrl;
        }
    }
    return oldNgView(viewDef);
}
ng.View = <ng.ViewFactory>ViewOverride;
```

*nb: It's very important to put it in a separate and independant file, to force it to be executed before other imports*

2) And put this as the **first** line of your bootstrap file:

```
import './viewoverride'
```

3) That's it. The @View notation is now overriden

```
@View({templateUrl:'mytemplate.template'}) class MyClass{}
```

will now  seek for a script element which id is `mytemplate.template`

Comment: another solution would be using Gulp to make a bundling process.

Comment: @Vincent As mentioned on my comment on the question's post, that's not an option: I'm generating my templates at runtime.

Comment: how about if multiple ng-template in one page?.. is this possible?

Comment: @AnthonyPillos I'm not sure to understand your question... yes, you can have multiple templates, all you have to do is to have one id per template

Comment: Ex. View({templateUrl:'mytemplate.template'}) class MyClass{}
this one is working.. i tested it already..
how about 2 @View in one .ts file..

View({templateUrl:'mytemplate.template'})
View({templateUrl:'mytemplate.other'})
class MyClass{}

or should i separate each class for each template coz it will only load the first View.. please enlighten me here.. thanks..

Comment: Two views on the same class ? No, that's not meant to work (angular does not support it)

Answer (score 4):

I think a cleaner way for this would be if you provide your custom `ViewResolver`, inspired by the angular *beta 17*'s source code, something in the lines of:

```ts
import { Type, ViewMetadata, Reflector, Injectable, ComponentMetadata } from 'angular2/core';
import { ViewResolver } from 'angular2/compiler';

const SCRIPT_TYPE_NAME = 'text/ng2-template';

@Injectable()
export class CustomViewResolver extends ViewResolver 
{
  constructor(private _r: Reflector){ super() }
  resolve(component: Type): ViewMetadata
  {
    let annotations = this._r.annotations(component);
    annotations.forEach( cm => 
    {
      if(cm instanceof ComponentMetadata && cm.templateUrl && typeof cm.templateUrl == 'string' )
      {
        let elemTpl = (<any>document).getElementById(cm.templateUrl);
        if( elemTpl && elemTpl.getAttribute('type') == SCRIPT_TYPE_NAME )
        {
          cm.template = elemTpl.innerHTML;
          elemTpl.remove();
          cm.templateUrl = undefined
        }
        else
          throw new Error(`template "${cm.templateUrl}" not found among html scripts`)
      }
    })
    return super.resolve(component)
  }
}
```

[**Plunker Link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2EIqCd7uWyTiKfTmfKzc?p=preview)