# How to define a template fom the `text/ng-template` source in angular2?

Tags: angular2-template

I am trying to apply the html from my internal `text/ng-template` script tag. but it's fails to work. how to apply `html` from the `script` tag?

Here is my code and html:

js part :

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: "template.html", //this is the id.
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  public title = "My Title";
  private userName = "Test Name";
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

HTML part :

```
      <body>
        <my-app>loading...</my-app>
//template declared
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">

          <h2>{{title}}</h2>
          <div>
            <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
            <h2>{{userName}}</h2>
          </div>

        </script>
      </body>
```

I am getting a error :

> Failed to load template.html

What is the correct way to use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template as <script type="text/ng-template"> equivalent with angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672836/template-as-script-type-text-ng-template-equivalent-with-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not, nor will be, supported in Angular 2 :\ https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6126